# Keeping a Play framework app running in a Docker container without a pseudo-TTY

Tags: playframework, docker, fig

I have a development setup where I need multiple containers running different services, and I'm trying to use [Fig](http://fig.sh) to achieve this. Everything else works fine, but one of these services is a Play Framework app, and it does not want to stay running unless it gets a pseudo-TTY. This would be fine and good, but since I want to coordinate these multiple containers, I want to `fig up`, and that command does not seem to allocate pseudo-TTY's, so the process dies immediately after startup, and all the containers along with it.

I've created [a repository with a showcase of this problem](https://github.com/ilkka/docker-play-test) that anybody can just clone and run, the instructions are in the README. If anybody can shed any light on how to create e.g. a middleman script that would keep the app running, or really any other solution where I could `fig up` my linked container setup, that'd be brilliant.

Alternatively, if anybody is using any other methods of coordinating multiple containers like this, like maybe a nice shell script runner that manages things, I welcome your insight.

**edit:** I changed the accepted answer because the new one actually solves the problem. The workaround answer still has valuable info, though.

Comment: Walp, I've given up. Since Play Framework contains the sbt native packager, one can `./activator docker:stage` and then run and build that. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/docker.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fig has been replaced by [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), and in your `docker-compose.yml` file you can now add the `stdin_open: true` setting, which should fix this issue:

```
web:  
  image: brikis98/ping-play
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  stdin_open: true
```

In the example above, the `brikis98/ping-play` image is a Play app that executes `activator run` by default. If I run `docker-compose up` on the YAML file above, the Play app boots up and keeps running instead of exiting immediately.

Answer (score 6):

A Play! run command orchestrated via Fig currently will always exit once launched. It is the same behaviour if you resumed the Fig created container (docker start -i). Basically this mirrors what happens when you launch the Play/SBT/Activator REPL via a run command as a Docker background daemon it will also exit (docker run -d).

The workaround as Ilkka already commented is to package the Play application to able to run on its own. Either via the stage and/or start commands https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production or as distribution via https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist.

For example if Docker image includes application source then you can add the stage command to it

```
ADD myapplication /var/local/application

WORKDIR /var/local/application 

RUN /usr/local/bin/activator stage
```

And in the fig.yml your command can be

```
command: target/universal/stage/bin/myapplication
```

You can see [an example Dockerfile](https://github.com/flurdy/docker-compose-machine-swarm-cloud-example/blob/master/frontend/Dockerfile) and [yml file](https://github.com/flurdy/docker-compose-machine-swarm-cloud-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) with this Docker Compose (Fig's successor) project

Answer (score 0):

fig run is supposed to use the TTY terminal. so you could try

```
fig run test ./activator start
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not do what up does.